# Adding header for dynamic pages on print

Tags: html, css, printing, header, print-preview

I have multiple tables that fill dynamically.

I want to print header on every pages in print mode, But when a table rows doesn't fit on the page they print on the next page and my header print on them.
Like this : [This is my print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlMFE.png)

how can I set a margin between page header and pages data?

I searched a lot but nothing seems to work, even position:fixed doesn't work as expected.

```
 @page {
       size: A4;
       margin-left: 0px;
       margin-right: 0px;
       margin-bottom: 0px;
       margin-top: 0px;
  }
@media screen {
     .header {
         display: none;
      }
  }

@media print {

    .header {
        position: fixed;
        top:10px;
        width:100%;
        margin:10px;
        border: 3px solid #000;
    }
}
```

**Sample Html:**

```
<table class="header">
    <tr>
        <td>
         This is my header table
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

<table>
   ....
</table>

<table>
  ....
</table>

and more...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a margin at the bottom of the header.

```
@media print {
    .header {
        width:100%;
        margin:10px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        border: 3px solid #000;
    }
}
```

This does not work to gether with `position: fixed;`, without it works.

Comment: Yes, I tried that ,tnx But unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: @SaMirakf I tried. When removing `position: fixed; top: 10px;` it works.

Comment: If i remove position:fixed  the header will print on one page while i want every pages